# darle un estilo cuadrado a los textview Android

Tags: java, android

Estimados tengo que darle un estilo parecido a este mockup 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero los text view que tengo son estos

```
            <TextView
            android:hint="@string/Reference"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/letter_grey"
            android:textColorHint="@color/letter_color_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reference"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/light_grey"/>
```

me gustaria saber si alguien me dice como dejarlos cuadriculados ya que no me quedan asi , actualmente estan asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo creado un drawable con la etiqueta shape. Crea un archivo en la carpeta drawable y llamalo `edit_text_border.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#fff">

    </solid>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#888" />
</shape>
```

Y en tu EditText:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/reference"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
            android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/light_grey"/>
```